# Configure IPv6 on FreeBSD webserver

Tags: networking, unix, freebsd, ipv6, bsd

Seems I just can't nail the right rc.conf configuration for IPv6 on my FreeBSD 10 VPS.
I'd like to go completely IPv6 and tutorials/instructions i followed aren't really working for me somehow.

It's just a basic, minimalistic web server VPS with one NIC.

**/etc/rc.conf**

```
ifconfig_vtnet0_ipv6="inet6 2a00:f48:1024:feed:b00b:feed:b3c9:c7c9 prefixlen 64"
ipv6_defaultrouter="2a00:f48:1024:feed::1"
rtsold_enable="YES"
ip6addrctl_policy="ipv6_prefer"
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 2001:4860:4860:8888
nameserver 2001:4860:4860:8844
```

Is that the right defaultrouter field value?
It would help if somebody suggested changes or shown their configs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the gateway address that should have been given to you by the VPS provider. Unfortunately, I know who your provider is, and they apparently do not tell the customer the gateway address as normal procedure, requiring a support ticket just to *learn* the gateway address.

Try `2a00:f48:1024::1`. If it doesn't work, open a ticket with the provider.

You will also need `prefixlen 48` with your IPv6 address.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why prefixlen 48 and why "unfortunately"?

Comment: Because they don't seem to know how to do IPv6 subnetting (or possibly that they can't). Everyone is thrown into the /48 and they don't further subnet it.

Comment: nah, tried, didn't work. :/